# SimpleCV for audio, or, Simple Computer Hearing in Python

Tags: python, pyaudio, simplecv

Is there an audio equivalent to the python SimpleCV library?

The description for SimpleCV is: "**With it, your software can have access to high level algorithms in feature detection, filtering, and pattern recognition in a unified framework.**"

Is there a "unified framework" for computer hearing using Python?

Answer (score -1):

you can check here:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic